# Does Mage::app()->cleanCache(); clear Magento Enterprise FPC?

Tags: cache, cron, full-page-cache, script

Does Mage::app()->cleanCache(); functionality clear Magento Enterprise Full Page Cache too or does another function/method have to be setup in our cache.php script? Here is what is in the script currently.

```
<?php
require_once '/home/website/website.com/html/app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to flush FPC in enterprise addition

```
Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()
            ->clean(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor::CACHE_TAG);
```